# [WEB]How to take input text from an input field and insert it into a different input field in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Okay so I'm trying to make a simple webpage that will take an input from an input field on my webpage and insert it into the search form for a page that's loaded in an iframe. I'm a beginner so pardon any obvious errors. I don't really know javascript well so this could be completely wrong. Help is much appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function searchStuff() {
      haruhichan.document.getElementById('searchSamaForm').searchSama.value = document.getElementById('srchtrm').value;
      haruhichan.document.getElementById('searchSamaForm').submit();
      }
</script>
<div>
Search Term:<input type="text" name="srchtrm" id="srchtrm" >
<input type="Button" value="Submit" onclick="searchStuff()" >
</div>
<div>
<iframe src="http://haruhichan.com/page/search/anime.html" name="haruhichan" style="width: 100%; height: 700px" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your domain is different from the `haruhichan.com` then there's no way you can change anything in the `iframe`, that comes under CORS.

Comment: Darn, thought that might be the case. I'm able to do a partial work around for sites with a GET method because then I can just parse the search terms into the url, but for a site like that they don't have the search parameters in the url and as far as I know there's no way to do it via url on that site. CORS looks interesting though. I can't wait for networked sites like that where you could have like 10 tech support sites all pulling data from each other.

Comment: They do have a search method REST method `/ajax.php?type=asearch` with form parameters, which you can call from your server to get JSON response. However I don't think they would be happy about that if they haven't exposed it as an API.